# How to convert pdf file to excel in c#

Tags: c#, excel, pdf, itext

I want to extract some data like `" email addresses "` .. from table which are in PDF file and use this email addresses which I extract to send email to those people.

What I have found so far through searching the web:

1. I have to convert the PDF file to Excel to read the data easily and use them as I want.
2. I find some free dll like `itextsharp` or `PDFsharp`.

But I didn't find any snippet code help to do this in C#. is there any solution ?

Comment: hope this link can give some light [https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a56b093b-2854-4925-99d5-2d35078c7cd3/converting-pdf-file-into-excel-file-using-c]

Comment: Thanks so much it's a great Link but it converts data from Excel to PDF . I need a snippet code convert from PDF to excel .

Comment: sorry..the link heading was viceversa thats why i posted it

Answer (score 5):

You absolutely do not have to convert PDF to Excel.
First of all, please determine whether your PDF contains textual data, or it is scanned image.
If it contains textual data, then you are right about using "some free dll". I recommend iTextSharp as it is popular and easy to use.

Now the controversial part. If you don't need rock solid solution, it would be easiest to read all PDF to a string and then retrieve emails using regular expression.
Here is example (not perfect) of reading PDF with iTextSharp and extracting emails:

```
public string PdfToString(string fileName)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();    
    var reader = new PdfReader(fileName);
    for (int page = 1; page <= reader.NumberOfPages; page++)
    {
        var strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
        string text = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, page, strategy);
        text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ASCIIEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(text)));
        sb.Append(text);
    }
    reader.Close();        
    return sb.ToString();
}
//adjust expression as needed
Regex emailRegex = new Regex("Email Address (?<email>.+?) Passport No");
public IEnumerable<string> ExtractEmails(string content)
{   
    var matches = emailRegex.Matches(content);
    foreach (Match m in matches)
    {
        yield return m.Groups["email"].Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: The pdf contains tabular data , it doesn't contain any scanned images .when I read data as text using itextsharp all the data in coloumn became in one line .

Comment: Thats why I recomended retrieving emails from that "one line" using regular expression. I rear cases it is not possible, but most of the time it is easiest solution.

Comment: If you still cannot figure this out, consider redacting sensitive information and giving us example of PDF document.

Comment: http://www.filedropper.com/decompany_1 ,,, in this link you will find an example of the pdf . I have to extract email address , name and other data  about salary to put them in the email body

Comment: I updated my answer with example of extracting multiple emails from your pdf. If you need to extract more information, you have to update regex and use more capture groups.

Comment: "iTextSharp is EOL, and has been replaced by iText 7" https://www.nuget.org/packages/iTextSharp/

Comment: Conversion is a good option if the layout is uniform and the text is variable enough that regular expressions would be risky. Acrobat has an Excel export feature that can convert a PDF into a well-formatted XLSX file. Rectangular grid elements are consistently mapped to the same cells. From there, you can select the exact content you need with cell references. That's safer than using regular expressions if the layout of your PDFs is predictable. Unfortunately, I haven't found a way to call it programmatically, but it can be automated with RPA.

Answer (score 1):

Using bytescout PDF Extractor SDK we can be able to extract the whole page to csv as below.

```
CSVExtractor extractor = new CSVExtractor();
extractor.RegistrationName = "demo";
extractor.RegistrationKey = "demo";

TableDetector tdetector = new TableDetector();
tdetector.RegistrationKey = "demo";
tdetector.RegistrationName = "demo";

// Load the document
extractor.LoadDocumentFromFile("C:\\sample.pdf");
tdetector.LoadDocumentFromFile("C:\\sample.pdf");

int pageCount = tdetector.GetPageCount();

for (int i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++)
{
    int j = 1;

        do
        {
                extractor.SetExtractionArea(tdetector.GetPageRect_Left(i),
                tdetector.GetPageRect_Top(i),
                tdetector.GetPageRect_Width(i),
                tdetector.GetPageRect_Height(i)
            );

            // and finally save the table into CSV file
            extractor.SavePageCSVToFile(i, "C:\\page-" + i + "-table-" + j + ".csv");
            j++;
        } while (tdetector.FindNextTable()); // search next table
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Probably the Best code would be to use Third party dll**

```
namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string pathToPdf = @"D:\abc\abc.pdf";
            string pathToExcel = Path.ChangeExtension(pathToPdf, ".xls");
            
            SautinSoft.PdfFocus f = new SautinSoft.PdfFocus();

   
            f.ExcelOptions.ConvertNonTabularDataToSpreadsheet = false;

            // 'true'  = Preserve original page layout.
            // 'false' = Place tables before text.
            f.ExcelOptions.PreservePageLayout = true;

            // The information includes the names for the culture, the writing system,
            // the calendar used, the sort order of strings, and formatting for dates and numbers.
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
            ci.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
            ci.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";
            f.ExcelOptions.CultureInfo = ci;

            f.OpenPdf(pathToPdf);

            if (f.PageCount > 0)
            {
                int result = f.ToExcel(pathToExcel);

                // Open the resulted Excel workbook.
                if (result == 0)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(pathToExcel);
                }
            }



        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
public void Convert(string fileNames) {
    int pageCount = 0;
    iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader reader = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(fileNames);
    pageCount = reader.NumberOfPages;
    string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileNames);

    //string[] outfiles = new string[pageCount];
    //Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
    //app.Workbooks.Add("");
    CSVExtractor extractor = new CSVExtractor();
    //string outfilePDF1 = fileNames.Replace((System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileNames)), (System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileNames).Replace(".pdf", "") + "_rez" + ".csv"));
    string outfilePDFExcel1 = fileNames.Replace((System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileNames)),
        (System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileNames).Replace(".pdf", "") + "_rez" + ".xls"));
    extractor.RegistrationName = "demo";
    extractor.RegistrationKey = "demo";

    string folderName = @"C:\Users\Dafina\Desktop\PDF_EditProject\PDF_EditProject\PDFs";
    string pathString = System.IO.Path.Combine(folderName, System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileNames).Replace(".pdf", "")) + "-CSVs";
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathString);
    for (int i = 0; i < pageCount; i++)
    {
        string outfilePDF = fileNames.Replace((System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileNames)),
            (System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileNames).Replace(".pdf", "") + "_" + (i + 1).ToString()) + ext);
        extractor.LoadDocumentFromFile(outfilePDF);
        //string outfile = fileNames.Replace((System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileNames)),
        //    (System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileNames).Replace(".pdf", "") + "_" + (i + 1).ToString()) + ".csv");
        string outfile = fileNames.Replace((System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileNames)),
            (System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileNames).Replace(".pdf", "") + "-CSVs\\" + "Sheet_" + (i + 1).ToString()) + ".csv");
        extractor.SaveCSVToFile(outfile);
    }
    Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

    if (xlApp == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Excel is not properly installed!!");
        return;
    }

    Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;


    object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
    string[] cvsFiles = Directory.GetFiles(pathString);
    Array.Sort(cvsFiles, new AlphanumComparatorFast());

    //string[] lista = new string[pageCount];
    //for (int t = 0; t < pageCount; t++)
    //{
    //    lista[t] = cvsFiles[t];           
    //}

    //Array.Sort(lista, new AlphanumComparatorFast());


    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
    for (int i = 0; i < cvsFiles.Length; i++)
    {
        int sheet = i + 1;
        xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets[sheet];

        if (i < cvsFiles.Length - 1)
        {
            xlWorkBook.Worksheets.Add(Type.Missing, xlWorkSheet, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        }


        int sheetRow = 1;
        Encoding objEncoding = Encoding.Default;
        StreamReader readerd = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(cvsFiles[i]));
        int ColumLength = 0;
        while (!readerd.EndOfStream)
        {
            string line = readerd.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(line);
            try
            {
                string[] columns = line.Split((new char[] { '\"' }));

                for (int col = 0; col < columns.Length; col++)
                {
                    if (ColumLength < columns.Length)
                    {
                        ColumLength = columns.Length;
                    }
                    if (col % 2 == 0)
                    {

                    }
                    else if (columns[col] == "")
                    {

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        xlWorkSheet.Cells[sheetRow, col + 1] = columns[col].Replace("\"", "");
                    }
                }
                sheetRow++;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                string msg = e.Message;
            }
        }

        int k = 1;
        for (int s = 1; s <= ColumLength; s++)
        {
            xlWorkSheet.Columns[k].Delete();
            k++;
        }



        releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
        readerd.Close();
    }

    xlWorkBook.SaveAs(outfilePDFExcel1, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal,
        misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive,
        misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
    xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);

    xlApp.Quit();

    releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
    releaseObject(xlApp);

    var dir = new DirectoryInfo(pathString);
    dir.Attributes = dir.Attributes & ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly;
    dir.Delete(true);

}
```